# How to find AD users where no password is set?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I find AD-users where the password has not been set?

Some backgrund information:

We have a script (written in C#) that creates AD users and sets a default password. The user is prompted to change this password at the first attempt to login.

The script runs fine but recently we discoverd that the password was not set in a few cases. And it keeps happening now and then. We are investigating this issue at the moment.

Now I wan't to find the users where the default password hasn't been set by the script in order to set the default password manually where required.

When I look at the AD attributes of a user I can't see an obvious way to find these users without (default) password set.

The pwdLastSet is 0x0 when the user is created form the script and the password has been set with succes (tested). So how to know when the password hasn't been set?

Comment: Well my first guess would be to check if there are any deactivated accounts?
Since the Passwort-Requirements are not fullfilled, the accounts should be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

What you are after is `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata`.

Give this one a go, you should be able to set it to what you need. It is fairly fast so you can add results to a hashtable and pump that out when done.
I have this pumped into a nice little function with `$Username` and `$ServerName` as `params`.

The main attributes you are after are `pwdLastSet`, `ntPwdHistory` and `lastLogonTimestamp`.

```
Get-ADuser $username |
Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata -Server $ServerName |
Where-Object Version -GT 1 | Select AttributeName, LastOriginatingChangeTime, Version | OGV
```

The `version` will tell you how many times it has been changed while the `LastOriginatingChangeTime` will tell you when. If you do a `Select *` and remove the `Where-Object Version -GT 1` you can see the other data it pulls.

**EDIT:**
Looks like Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata is not available on version 2.

```
PSVersion Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata
--------- ----------------------------------
        2                              False
        3                               True
        4                               True
        5                               True
```

Comment: Nice, a version-less `ntPwdHistory` is probably the best indicator here

Comment: Thanks voor responding. But seems like Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata is not available to me. Not recognized is what I get when I try this.

Comment: Checked version compatibility for you.

Comment: Thanks, did version check on my PC and I'm running version 4.
>get-host|Select-Object version

Version                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------                                                                                                                                                                                       
4.0

Answer (score 1):

The PasswordLastSet attribut could do it. It saves the date when the password was set the last time.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties PasswordLastSet | Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null }
```

Comment: The issue with this is passwordlastset will return a 0 if there is not password and if they need to set a new password when first logging in.

Comment: ActiveDirectory dates are numeric, and must be translated to get a datetime value. This mostly happens automatically, but sometimes it can be in pain. In this case it can work for you. You can get the property as a number, and then just check if it's <= the `whenCreated` attribute, which is also a date you can retrieve as a number.

Comment: I've tried this before posting my question here. It's not telling me what  I want to know as Matthew responded. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It **IS** possible to have users in AD that have a blank password, despite activated password policy. This is due to the `PASSWD_NOTREQD` flag in the `userAccountControl` property of a user. The value for this PASSWD_NOTREQD flag is 32.

To check for enabled users that have this flag (and therefore don't need a password) you can do

```
$noPwdRequired = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=544))"
foreach($user in $noPwdRequired ){
     Write-Host $user.sAMAccountName  # or displayName or whatever  you want to identify the user
}
```

Normally, a user object has the default value of 512 (`NORMAL_ACCOUNT`). With the `PASSWD_NOTREQD` they will have a value of 544

Use value 546 to find disabled accounts that also has this flag set.

You can update this for any of those found users doing something like

```
$noPwdRequired = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=544))"
foreach($user in $noPwdRequired ){
     Set-ADAccountControl $user -PasswordNotRequired $false
}
```